# PHP automatic navigation-bar from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have navigation folders structure stored in mysql:

[image: navigation structure]

I have this navigation:

[image]

Now I need to make automatic detect parent's folders and create navigation information bar for all levels parent-folders but I dont know how, I have only first level parent.

[image]

How I can create loop and stop automatically when `parent` is `0`?

Here is my function:

```
    public static function Gallery($fid = NULL){

    $folder_id  =   $fid ? $fid : 1;
    echo "<div class=\"gallery-c\">";
    echo "<div class=\"gallery-path--c\">";

    $current_path_obj       =   Database::dbquery("SELECT * FROM calendar_gallery_folders WHERE id = $fid", false, true)['result'][0];
    $current_path_name      =   $current_path_obj->folder;
    $current_path_parent    =   $current_path_obj->parent;
    $parent_path_name       =   Database::dbquery("SELECT folder FROM calendar_gallery_folders WHERE id = $current_path_parent", false, true)['result'][0]->folder;

    // Navigation information bar
    echo $parent_path_name."/".$current_path_name;

    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class=\"gallery-folder--c\">";
    // Folders
    foreach(Database::dbquery("SELECT * FROM calendar_gallery_folders WHERE parent = $folder_id ORDER BY id", false, true)['result'] as $folder){
        echo "<a class=\"js-gallery-folderlink gallery-folder--box\" data-folder=\"$folder->id\">
        <div class=\"gallery-folder--icon\"><span class=\"icon material-symbols-outlined\">folder</span></div>
        <div class=\"gallery-folder--text\">$folder->folder</div></a>";
    }

    echo "</div>";

    echo "</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get all the folders in an array and do recursive looping.

```
public static function Gallery($fid = NULL){

    $folder_id  =   $fid ? $fid : 1;
    echo "<div class=\"gallery-c\">";
    echo "<div class=\"gallery-path--c\">";

    $all_folders       =   Database::dbquery("SELECT * FROM calendar_gallery_folders", false, true)['result'];
    //Map result with Key ID
    $folders_map = [];
    foreach($all_folders as $folder){
        $folders_map[$folder->id]=$folder;
    }
    //Recrusive Loop function to get the trail
    $navigation = getTrail($folders_map,$fid);

    //Reverse the result 
    $navigation = array_reverse($navigation);
    //Print the navigation
    echo implode('/',$navigation)
    

    echo "</div>";

    echo "</div>";
}
function getTrail($folder_map,$folder_id,$trail=[]){
    if(isset($folder_map[$folder_id])){
        array_push($trail,$folder_map[$folder_id]->folder);
    }else{
        return [];
    }

    if($folder_map[$folder_id]->parent!=0){
        $trail = $this->getTrail($folder_map,$folder_map[$folder_id]->parent,$trail);
    }
    return $trail;
}
```